# What does the colon and :a in the attribute name of the removeAttr('xmlns:a') function parameter in jQuery mean?

Tags: jquery, svg, xml-namespaces

```html
<a class="but-arrow" href="">
    <img class="svg" src="img/icons/arrow.svg" alt="" />
</a>
```

```js
function svg() {
    $('img[src$=".svg"]').each(function () {
        var $img = $(this)
        var imgURL = $img.attr('src')
        var attributes = $img.prop('attributes')
        if ($img.hasClass('svg')) {
            $.get(
                imgURL,
                function (data) {
                    var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg')
                    $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a')
                    $.each(attributes, function () {
                        $svg.attr(this.name, this.value)
                    })
                    $img.removeClass('svg').replaceWith($svg)
                },
                'xml'
            )
        }
    })
}
svg()
```

```xml
<svg width="16" height="17" viewBox="0 0 16 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M4.07812 13.9866L5.25812 15.1666L11.9248 8.49998L5.25812 1.83331L4.07812 3.01331L9.56479 8.49998L4.07812 13.9866Z" fill="#868686"/>
</svg>
```

HTML in arrow.svg

What does the colon and :a mean here in `$svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a')`? Represents a namespace?

I know that the jQuery event has a dot "." to represent the namespace, but I have never seen a colon.

Comment: In JavaScript/jQuery? Nothing, it's just another character in a string. Otherwise see:

Comment: Also what is the purpose of removing the namespace? The code will not work since there is no :a in the namespace in the provided SVG

Comment: @mplungjan This is someone else's code, I just want to understand why he uses it like this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The point of my question isn't XML namespaces, I'm just saying it's like.